# Response header name 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' contains invalid characters, aborting rew#quest

Tags: laravel, cors, laravel-5

I have a laravel app (deployed on heroku) where I am receiving a 500 Internal Server error.

When I checked my logs, I get the error metheod in the title:

Response header name 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin ' contains invalid characters, aborting request

I have a cors middleware with the following code:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin : *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers : Content-type, 
X-Auth-Token, Authorization, Origin');
return $next($request);
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try it without the space before the semicolon like this `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` maybe the browser doesn't like it?

Answer (score -1):

Use this package, I was used couple of time it's work for me.
https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-cors